# Можно ли так оформить прямую речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

Там впервые за девять лет – начиная с оккупации их деревни венгерскими войсками – она вновь смогла спокойно спать: «Я наконец спала, не опасаясь, что меня убьют за то, что я еврейка».

Можно ли так оформить прямую речь?

Или будет правильно так:

Там впервые за девять лет – начиная с оккупации их деревни венгерскими войсками – она вновь смогла спокойно спать. «Я наконец спала, не опасаясь, что меня убьют за то, что я еврейка».

Там впервые за девять лет – начиная с оккупации их деревни венгерскими войсками – она вновь смогла спокойно спать.

«Я наконец спала, не опасаясь, что меня убьют за то, что я еврейка», - говорит она.

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

Там впервые за девять лет – начиная с оккупации их деревни венгерскими войсками – она вновь смогла спокойно спать. «Я наконец спала не опасаясь, что меня убьют за то, что я еврейка», - пишет она в своих воспоминаниях.

Здесь более распространенные слова автора с дополнительной информацией для читателя и с большим объемом текста "для его равновесия" при чтении.

Также можно не ставить запятую перед "опасаясь" -  тогда подчеркивается тесная связь обстоятельства со сказуемым, ударение падает на деепричастие.